# Sports Analytics is in commitment phase!

Tags: discussion, se-sites, area51, stackexchange

After reaching 202 followers since it was proposed in September 2016, [Sports Analytics](https://area51.stackexchange.com/proposals/102995/sports-analytics) Stack Exchange entered in the commitment phase last 14th August.

Let's remember what is this site about:

> Proposed Q&A site for analysts wanting advice or feedback on their methods, models or metrics, and for anyone requesting specific statistics about the sports they follow. It's not a venue to share licensed data or discuss scraping commercial web sites.

As of 21th August 2017 it has 66 users committed, so I encourage you all to commit as well and make it possible to have yet another Stack Exchange site for Sports enthusiasts.

[image: Stack Exchange Q&A site proposal: Sports Analytics]

I do think it is going to be a good place for many [trivia](https://sports.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/trivia) questions that need quite a lot of data digging.

Answer (score 4):

[ For avoidance of doubt: the below are my personal views. They do not represent the views of the Sports SE moderators or anybody other than myself. ]

I'm not convinced we need a separate site for this. The biggest thing stopping Sports SE moving from beta into a public site is a lack of questions - I'd be more than happy to see the sort of questions being proposed for Sports Analytics right here on this site, and I think they are covered by the "hobbyists, and fans of all sports" part of our [scope](https://sports.stackexchange.com/help/on-topic). We might need to tweak the "don't ask" bit of the scope slightly to make it clear that *quantitative* questions about "the better [team/athlete/etc.]" and "Who will win the [event/award/etc.]" are on-topic, but that doesn't seem to be a problem to me - but I'll freely admit to being a data geek :-)

Comment: +1. Happy to see that it's not only my concern that suggested Sports Analytics site can possibly take away some questions (which are essential for us for graduation) that are very on-topic on our site.

Comment: Currently, [we have about 2 questions per day](https://area51.stackexchange.com/proposals/27135/sports) and [it is not getting any better](http://data.stackexchange.com/sports/query/716660/questions-asked-by-week#graph). We lack questions, this is right, but currently the front page is filled with [tag:trivia] questions that do not add much value apart from doing some googling. Sports Analytics.SE would help cleaning those and to provide better answers to them through more formal research methods.

Comment: Also, I see pretty interesting [example questions](https://area51.stackexchange.com/proposals/102995?phase=definition) like _How do we objectively adjust players' metrics based on the league they play in so we have a level base upon which to compare all players?_, _What statistical distribution best captures goal difference in football?_, _Is it feasible to use something like OpenCV to capture player movement data (w/ static or 'tactical' camera footage)?_ and others that would clearly be off topic in [sports.se] since they are more programming+statistics related.

Comment: @fedorqui, first of all that is one fn amazing query! Thank you for that! Secondly, the trivia questions on our front page you mentioned, I agree, we should answer with more formal research methods, but IMO still on Sports SE - we just need to define canonical methods on meta for doing so. And finally, the questions you mentioned in your last comment may be asked on SO, Cross Validated - although I'm not sure about it, but you are right definitely not on Sports SE.

Comment: The value in a separate site is that you have the possibility of attracting experts.  I can't imagine many analytics experts being attracted to Sports.SE as it is now; we have very few questions on that topic, and the ones we do have don't usually get very good answers.  Attracting experts is one of the key ways a Stack grows.